# iOS10 cordova Status bar overlap with content

Tags: iphone, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova with the following configs:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

Plugins I use is:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.2.3" />
```

I am still getting a statusbar that overlaps with my web content? Why?

Comment: do you have a Content-Security-Policy meta tag in your index.html?

Comment: yes I have. does it matter? Cant remember why I have it. I tried to remove it but looks like still overlapping.

Comment: do you have gap: on the default-src? if you don't, that might prevent plugins from working, add gap: and try again

Comment: thanks i think you pointed me to the right direction! but somehow, it is still not working...

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the culprit - Admob plugin.

Initialising Admob with "offsetTopBar: true" solves my problem - statusbar no longer overlaps with content:

```
        AdMob.createBanner({
            adId: "...", 
            position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, 
            isTesting: false,
            autoShow: true,
            orientationRenew: true,
            overlap: false,
            offsetTopBar: true}
        )
```

Source: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/blob/master/docs/README.md